# Disconnected external monitor stays the primary monitor after disconnecting

Tags: display

If I disconnect my external monitor, simply by unplugging the HDMI connector, Ubuntu seems to think it is still there. Windows stay there, and and if I open new windows they are shown there, ie I cant see them!

Is there a way to fix this?

I run Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

Answer (score 3):

When in the described situation, that the main monitor is there in Ubuntu, but there is no actual monitor, I found one solution. Simply run the "Displays" thing, well press the <kbd>Super</kbd> button, type "Displays", and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As soon as that configuration window open, it realizes that there is no monitor, and all windows are moved to the laptop's monitor. You can select alter the primary monitor so that, you don't have to go through this always.

Other solutions are welcome too.